# element.scrollTop/left is really slow in Safari, why?

Tags: javascript, performance, web, safari, webkit

When the given HTML code below is loaded in Safari 6.0.8, the scroll function executes in ~1500 ms. In Chrome that number is ~50 ms and in FireFox ~5 ms.
I've identified the scroll methods to be the culprits, but I can't figure out why Safari is so damn slow executing them. Is it an implementation detail of Safari, or am I doing something wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .container {
            width: 20%;
            height: 100px;
            background: #FF9800;
            position: relative;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="top">
        <!-- 500 of these will be generated and added to the #top element -->
        <div class="container">
            <div style="position: absolute; left: -1px; top: -1px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow: scroll; z-index: -1; visibility: hidden;">
                <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow: scroll; z-index: -1; visibility: hidden;">
                    <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 294.796875px; height: 110px;"></div>
                </div>
                <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow: scroll; z-index: -1; visibility: hidden;">
                    <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 200%; height: 200%;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        //Generates the 500 container elements.
        var numElements = 499;
        var containerOriginal = document.querySelector(".container");
        for(var i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
            var container = containerOriginal.cloneNode(true);
            document.getElementById("top").appendChild(container);
        }


        //Why is this function so slow in Safari?
        function scroll(el, et, sl, st) {
            var containers = document.querySelectorAll(".container");
            for(var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
                var container = containers[i];
                var expand = container.children[0].children[0];
                var shrink = container.children[0].children[1];
                expand.scrollLeft   = el;
                expand.scrollTop    = et;
                shrink.scrollLeft   = sl;
                shrink.scrollTop    = st;
            }
        }

        //Execute the actual test on document ready.
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            console.time("test");
            scroll(9, 9, 144, 101);
            console.timeEnd("test");
        }, false);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To my best guess of why this is so slow is because you are trying to load many elements. What I would suggest instead of

```
var expand = container.children[0].children[0];
var shrink = container.children[0].children[1];
```

putting a class on these children elements you are wanting to get and getting them that way.

Comment: Thanks, but those lines are not the reason. When commenting out the element.scroll* lines, the function executes in ~1.5 ms.